# Can I use this chainlink?

Tags: chain

I bought this SRAM PC1091 chain for my compact chainset and have been running it since January. In order for the chain to fit properly I cut a few links from it.
I am now getting a standard chainset, so I think I will have to add some links back on the chain.

Can I reattach this link to my chain to make it longer? This is how I left it when I chopped it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it leaves the chain weaker on that link.

The SRAM chains are designed to [work with a master link](http://www.competitivecyclist.com/product-components/2012-sram-10-speed-power-link-pack-of-4-5696.23.1.html). If you use that one, it's not reusable, but it comes in a pack of 4, so you can open and close it a few times for cleaning.

Comment: Thanks. As I'll have to disconnect the chain's power lock anyway I'll end up with two power locks on it I think.

Comment: You can definitely get away with re-using powerlinks a few times on SRAM chains. I havn't really had any issues.  I use a  Park MLP-1 to remove them and snap them back on by hand.  Really, breaking the chain with a chain tool every time is a waste.

Comment: @Benzo: You can do it, physically, yes. But it weakens the link, and it will separate at some point. They are designed not to be reused.